# Related to use of irony in a sentence

Tags: grammar

In Dostoyevsky's novella "Notes from underground", after the narrator gave a long speech to convince(maybe) Liza about happiness in being with family, there is a sentence which Liza said and this is excerpt from the book

"Why, you ... Speak somehow like a book," she said, and again there was a note of irony in her voice.

What is the irony in this.i know that irony is when there is contrast between literal meaning and intended meaning.but here do irony mean she was mocking him or she wanted to make fun of him.

Comment: It's not possible to say how this is ironic without knowing the context surrounding the speech.

Answer (score 1):

Meaning of  [***irony***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/irony)

Though the narrator wanted to convince Liza of the happiness in living with family but this effort produced a opposite result that Liza began insulting the narrator. So this is the irony.